# Error in Entity Framework 6.0.2 using "Migration"

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, migration, nuget

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm using Entity Framework 6.0.2 for data persistence. After creating all the entities ("Model"), using the Data Annotation, I used "Migration" to create the Pack, but after the database is not criano in SQL Server 2012, the Nuget message "Sequence contains no matching element" is displayed

The "connection string" is configured, and the SQL Server 2012 is active.

I used the command:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations


PM>Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Configure>b__0(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
```

Comment: `Eneble-Migrations` I hope that was a copy-paste fail or a typo on here

Comment: Are you migrating any data over from one version to another? If so, could you please post that code?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me - can you file this using https://entityframework.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create ? Please provide a repro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thought it was bug in Visual Studio, or even in classes or references to the Entity Framework installation.
The only problem was,  "DOUBLE" attributes. Was using the wrong notation.
ex:
Instead of using:

```
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a Nota do Aluno")]
        [Column("NotaAluno", TypeName = "Decimal(3,2)")]
        [DisplayName("Nota do Aluno:*")]
        public Double dNotaAluno { get; set; }
```

Use this:

```
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}",
            ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
            NullDisplayText = "Sem Nota")]
        [Range(0, 100, ErrorMessage = "A nota deverá ser entre 0 a 100.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a Nota do Aluno")]
        [Column("NotaAluno", TypeName = "decimal")]
        [DisplayName("Nota do Aluno:*")]
        public decimal dNota { get; set; }
```

Small problem, lack of attention in the creation of class and respect the primitive types of SQL Server.
Thanks.

Comment: The lack of attention was on the part of whoever thought "Sequence contains no matching element" was sufficient error information for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while trying to migrate from sql server to mysql and I just found it was because using datetime2. Sugested fix that worked for me : use plain old DateTime